# What is the exponential for the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

What is the exponential for the matrix

$$     \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -x & 0 \\
        x & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is it $$     \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos x & -\sin x & 0 \\
        \sin x & \cos x & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: A quick search would have answered your question for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: @sarah: that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Exponential of a matrix is defined using Taylor series, *viz*
$$e^A=I+A+\frac12A^2+...=\sum_{n=1}\frac1{n!}A^n$$